# How did Starfleet crew its ships during the Dominion War?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

How did Starfleet crew its ships during the Dominion War? Romulan Senator Vrenak said the were encountering a manpower shortage and that was comparatively early in the war.

It makes sense. Training can be truncated but starships are highly technical and with new ship construction as well as losses, training new crew and especially officers would have been an extraordinarily difficult and time consuming. The Dominion could breed more Jem'Hadar but how could the Federation cope with the demands of war?

Comment: They did what normally happens in a war, shortened officer training and encouraged enrollment.

Comment: They probably also cancelled shore leave, cancelled sabbaticals and cancelled non-military applications such as exploration, science research and terraforming.

Answer (score 6):

War traditionally makes recruiting for the military easier so there was most likely an upsurge of volunteers for Starfleet.

Training time can usually be greatly reduced the highly advanced nature of the federation tech likely would make this easier.

Loss of personnel may not be as critical of an issue in an era of escape pods especially in large scale battles.

Finally existing crew could be repurposed most ships crewed for wartime would likely not have dedicated science personnel, a large security crew, a large medical staff or a large repair crew

Comment: I think wartime ships wouldn't likely skip on repair or medical staff, but I think your point still stands.

Comment: @nexus What I meant was I see each ship only having a small staff for triage situations, instead of trying to fix something you stabilize it until you can get off the front line